# Suppress unimplemented methods in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, methods, error-suppression

Is it possible to suppress the unimplemented methods error in eclipse? If so, is this a smart thing to do or will this cause possible instability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot suppress this, because it is not a warning.  You would be breaking the contract of an `interface` or an `abstract class` by not implementing their abstract methods.

It is not a smart thing to do, because your code would not compile.